# Power series area of convergence with $\sin$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I want to examine for which $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2x-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ converges. So far I have tried to use the inequality $\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ and find the convergence area of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2x-1)^n}{n^2}$$ but I am not sure how this might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = (2x - 1 )^n \sin \Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)$. Then

$$\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lim \bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg| &= \lim \frac{|(2x - 1)|^{\color{#05f}{\cancel {n}}+1}}{\color{#05f}{\cancel{|(2x - 1)|^n}}}\frac{\sin (1/(n+1)^2)}{\sin (1/n^n)} \\&= \lim |(2x - 1)| \frac{n^2}{(n + 1)^2}\frac{\frac{\sin(1/(n+1)^2)}{1/(n+1)^2}}{\frac{\sin(1/n^2)}{1/n^2}} = |2x - 1|\end{align}$$

Then  if $|2x - 1| < 1$ we have that the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ratio test for the last series to see the 
$$ |2x-1|<1 \implies 0<x<1 .$$

Comment: I did that, but how do we know that the last has the same area of convergence with the first?

Comment: Next time you should show your work!